Deterministic Property not Working as Expected in UDF
I am creating an UDF expecting to be deterministic, i.e., it should give same result for same input. But it is not working as expected when the table is updated.
Step #1. Create a table and insert few records.
CREATE TABLE dbo.determin_function_test_table
(
  empid int,
  ename varchar(100),
  dob date
);

INSERT dbo.determin_function_test_table(empid, ename, dob) 
VALUES (101,'Arun','1990-01-01'),(102,'Bala','1990-02-02'),(103,'Chitra','1990-03-03');

Step #2. Create a deterministic function (WITH SCHEMABINDING)
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.determin_function_test_udf
(
  @p_empid int
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT ename FROM dbo.determin_function_test_table WHERE empid = @p_empid);
END
GO

Step #3. Select the function. Result and deterministic property is good in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where specific_name = 'determin_function_test_udf'
and is_deterministic = 'YES';

select dbo.determin_function_test_udf(101) as emp_name;
select dbo.determin_function_test_udf(102) as emp_name;
select dbo.determin_function_test_udf(103) as emp_name;

Step 4. Update a record.
update dbo.determin_function_test_table
set ename = 'Chitra Dhana'
where empid = 103;

Step 5. Call the UDF for that empid.
select dbo.determin_function_test_udf(103) as emp_name;

Now the expected result is Chitra, the old value. But the function returns Chitra Dhana, the new value.
I have a similar function, which queries a huge table and returns a set of values (in a comma-separated string). My expectation is to avoid the execution of the entire function each time when it is called with same inputs.

Why would you expect the old value after you UPDATEd it?

That's not what Deterministic means. It means that if the database doesn't change then for the same input you get the same result. On a side note: avoid scalar UDFs like the plague, they are slow and cause all sorts of problems. This can be easily rewritten as an inline TVF CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.determin_function_test (@p_empid int) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (SELECT t.ename FROM dbo.determin_function_test_table t WHERE t.empid = @p_empid);

This function should be trivially inlinable by the inline scalar UDF feature anyway though and is simple enough that it shouldn't hit any of the issues with that

Hi @ThomA, This is just an example. The actual requirement is when an input is given to the function, the control should go inside the function and return the result. When the same input is given again, the result should be returned without executing the statements in the function, as the result is already been calculated for the input. Is it possible to achieve?

If you don't want to execute the function again, store the value in a variable. There is no "if you ran the statement earlier, remember what you did then instead" feature.

Let's say you had such function and it would be possible. Wouldn't sql server have to store all possible results somewhere?
And how would you "flush" the result so it gets recalculated?

Hi @siggemannen, I expected some kind of cache in the server to store the results. For the flush, I wanted to check if anything equivalent of DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.FLUSH in Oracle.
From the inputs from ThomA and Charlieface, I understand that it is different in SQL Server. Thanks!

Yeah, it just doesn't work like this, most sql server developers would expect the function result to be different when you change the underlying data. There's something called result set caching, but it actually assumes that data is the same. But also, in general, you're probably thinking with oracle colored glasses, one generally doesn't use functions to "query large tables returning set of values", they are mostly for calculating commonly executed calculations and formulas or for string manipulation. If you want such "call" cache, i suggest creating a stored procedure and a cache table

As @Thom A said to avoid the function calling again, store the results in temporary view or table indexing it.
Upon any update to the table, you set up the trigger which updates the data in the above created view or table.
Something like below.
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_ename_cached
ON dbo.determin_function_test_table
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET ename_cached = dbo.determin_function_test_udf(i.empid)
    FROM dbo.temp_cahed_table t
    INNER JOIN determin_function_test_table i ON t.empid = i.empid;
END;

Also, i have tried to add new column to precompute the values making it persist using below query.
ALTER TABLE dbo.determin_function_test_table
ADD ename_computed AS (dbo.determin_function_test_udf()) PERSISTED;

I got below error.

I found out according to this documentation the column expression should be deterministic.
But still i am getting error because the function gives same results until the table is updated, once it is updated need to compute again.

@MartinSmith thank you for mentioning i have updated the solution.
